# pexpect.EOF error while expect/sendline password

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, pexpect

I am running this command on unix environment. but i am having these continuous issues !
OUTPUT:
after: 
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: True
pid: 17368
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: 
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1

```
mycode:
p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "depndnt setup_links:pure-python-2.7,host=myhost1"')
p.expect ('password:')
p.sendline ('mypassword')
p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
print(p.before)
```

Comment: Please show your attempts to write that code.

Comment: unrelated: you could write it as: `output, status = pexpect.run(command, events={'(?i)password:': 'mypassword'}, withexitstatus=1)`